# Ключевое слово not в VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Почему в `VS15` не определено ключевое слово `not`?

Comment: вы имеете в виду not как логический оператор?

Comment: @simplygood http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/not

Comment: никогда не видел c++ в котором используется not :), используйте вместо этого '!'

Comment: определите через #define на здоровье)))) `#define not !` правда могут возникнуть конфликты имён - но это другой вопрос.

Comment: @simplygood я не должен пользоваться тем, что вы никогда не видели?

Comment: Прочитайте внимательнее свою же собственную ссылку. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative Там написано, когда и как это используется.

Comment: @Zealint 1) это не моя ссылка; 2) вопрос не об этом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, оно определено. Только надо в свойствах проекта отключить использование собственных расширений языка.:)

Входите в меню "Проект", затем внизу меню выбираете свойства вашего проекта. А затем в закладке С/С++ - Язык отключаете "Отключить расширения языка".

Comment: Спасибо, а что именно блокирует его? Можно не отключать всё, а только этот блок?

Comment: @user228168 Честно говоря, я не интересовался, как отдельно активизировать только использование этих ключевых слов. Возможно, имеется макрос, который если определен, то либо активизирует использование этих ключевых слов, либо нет. Это надо искать на сайте Майкрософт.:)

Comment: @user228168, но лучше этого не делать и оставить идею использования `not`, т.к. отключение расширений создаст [больше проблем](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/MSVC-Za-considered-harmful-td4024306.html), чем решит.

Comment: @ixSci у меня просто стоит задача написать программу на английском)

Comment: @ixSci кстати, обновляйте блог почаще)

Comment: @ixSci Это несколько устаревшие сведения. Вопрос же касается vS15. Желательно знать состояние дел для этой среды.

Comment: @ixSci Вон на меня как наехали на SO, хотя мой ответ полностью корректный!:)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648011/c-vector-keyword-ref/40648279#40648279

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, я нашёл эту ссылку, но узнал я это из какого-то видео(от Стефана), которое было явно позже выхода MSVC2015. [Тут](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/55gugf/cppcon_2016_carroll_moth_latest_and_greatest_from/) ещё есть комментарии от Стефана, подтверждающие, что ничего не изменилось и что этого флага лучше избегать. А на счёт enSO — бывает. У меня там есть принятый ответ, с -10.

Comment: @user228168, если это просто академическое развлечение, тогда ничего страшного. Просто не пытайтесь использовать этот флаг в коммерческих продуктах. Что касается блога — в ближайшее время планирую вернуться к нему.